# How to create a keystroke monitor windows services in win10?

Tags: python, windows-services, keystroke

I want to record press time and release time of related key and write this information to file in the background. I implement it with python and pack python script into a windows executable file. When I double click this executable file, it works normally, however, when I use `"sc.exe"` tool to transform it into a windows service, it doesn't work.

I have tried the `"win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework"`(python api of windows services), it also doesn't work.

Comment: provide a [mcve], and explain what you mean by "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Haddad

I want to use Keyrecorder_Win.py to record the keystorke information, and use ServiceLauncher.py or "sc.exe" to wrap "Keyrecorder" into a Windows service. 
"It doesn't work" can be classified into 2 situation:

- situation 1:

  When I execute Keyrecorder_win.py, it works normally, but when I put windows into sleep, and wake up it later, it cannot write the keystroke information to file any more.
- situation 2:

  When I wrap python script into Windows service and launch service in the background, it also cannot write infomation to file.

My purpose is running this monitor program on the backgroud, and hope it works fine even if when I wake up my computer from sleep status.

Here blow is my code:

Keyrecorder_Win.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8
import pythoncom
import pyHook
import time
import os
import re 
press_stack = []
release_stack = []
class Keyrecorder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_result_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Result")
        if not os.path.exists(self.path_result_dir):
            os.mkdir(self.path_result_dir)

    def Time2Date(self, sec):
        time_struct = time.localtime(sec)
        time_string = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time_struct)
        return time_string

    def onKeyboardEvent(self, event):
        time_string = self.Time2Date(time.time())
        fp = os.path.join(self.path_result_dir, time_string + ".txt")

        if not os.path.exists(fp):
            fobj = open(fp, "w")
        else:
            fobj = open(fp, "a+")
        press_time = -1
        release_time = -1
        event_type = event.MessageName # press or release
        event_key = event.Key # related key

        if event_type == "key down":
            press_time = int(time.time()*10**6)
            press_stack.append((event_key, press_time))
        elif event_type == "key up":
            release_time = int(time.time()*10**6)
            release_stack.append((event_key, release_time))

        len1 = len(press_stack)
        len2 = len(release_stack)
        if len1 > 0 and len1 == len2:
            is_reverse = press_stack[0][0] != release_stack[0][0]
            # press key in turn，but release key in reverse order
            if len1 == 2 and is_reverse:
                while len(release_stack) > 0:
                    p = press_stack.pop(0)
                    r = release_stack.pop()
                    duration = r[1] - p[1]
                    record = "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n" % (p[0], p[1], r[1], duration)
                    fobj.write(record)
                    fobj.flush()

            # press and release key in turn 
            elif len1 >= 1 and not is_reverse:
                while len(release_stack) > 0:
                    p = press_stack.pop(0)
                    r = release_stack.pop(0)
                    duration = r[1] - p[1]
                    record = "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n" % (p[0], p[1], r[1], duration)
                    fobj.write(record)
                    fobj.flush()

            # function key firstly be pressed，then other keys be pressed. 
            # other key be released firstly then release function key. 
            elif len1 > 2 and is_reverse:
                p = press_stack.pop(0)
                r = release_stack.pop()
                duration = r[1] - p[1]
                record = "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n" % (p[0], p[1], r[1], duration)
                fobj.write(record)
                fobj.flush()

                while len(release_stack) > 0:
                    p = press_stack.pop(0)
                    r = release_stack.pop(0)
                    duration = r[1] - p[1]
                    record = "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n" % (p[0], p[1], r[1], duration)
                    fobj.write(record)
                    fobj.flush()
        if fobj and not fobj.closed:
            fobj.flush()
            fobj.close()

        return True

    def record(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        hm = pyHook.HookManager()
        hm.KeyAll = self.onKeyboardEvent
        hm.HookKeyboard()
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

def main():
    kr = Keyrecorder()
    kr.record()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ServiceLauncher.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import winerror
import servicemanager
import os
import sys

class ServiceLauncher(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'Keyrecord'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Keyrecord'
    _svc_description_ = "Keyrecord for windows"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.run = True

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import KeyRecorder_Win
        kr = KeyRecorder_Win.Keyrecorder()
        kr.record()

if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        try:
            evtsrc_dll = os.path.abspath(servicemanager.__file__)
            servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(ServiceLauncher)
            servicemanager.Initialize('ServiceLauncher', evtsrc_dll)
            servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
        except win32service.error, details:
            if details[0] == winerror.ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT:
                win32serviceutil.usage()
            else:
                win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ServiceLauncher)
```

Comment: @Alan Do you have some opinions?